# wget without any headers

Tags: header, wget

I would like to get the files without headers. I have tried many things like

```
wget --header="" http://xxxxx.xxxxxx.xx
```

How can I get any files without headers?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't quite answer the question, but I got here by looking up "remove default header wget" so I'll put in my 2 cents.

You can remove the User-Agent header with `-U ""`. This was useful for me because the Geometry Dash servers will reject your request if it has a user agent.

Answer (score -1):

Could you assign the output of `wget` to a string, then use something else to process it to drop headers (or parse them out of the text)?

For example, using `bash` and `grep`, you can store the html from a webpage as a string, then use `grep` to extract the text in the `<body>` section:

```
w1=$(wget --quiet --output-document - www.example.com)
echo $w1 | grep --only-matching "<body>.*</body>"
```

which gives the output below (I have added some newlines to improve how it displays here):

```
<body> <div> 
<h1>Example Domain</h1> <p> 
This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents.
You may use this domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for 
 permission.
</p> <p>
<a href="http://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p> 
</div> </body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's what they mean - I interpreted it as "don't send headers to the server"